# Changing the page number in Excel each time I print

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, vba, page-numbers

I want to add an additional input box for range printing.

I changed the code from [this post](https://superuser.com/a/203914/50173) to include another input box to determine the number range and to printpreview instead of printing if possible.

So the code asks:

- How many copies do you want?  (e.g. 10)
- What number do you want to start at?  (e.g 50)

Now Excel prints 10 copies numbered 50 -60

```
Sub PrintCopies_ActiveSheet()

    Dim CopiesCount As Long 
    Dim CopyNumber As Long 
    Dim StartNumber As Integer 

    CopiesCount = Application.InputBox("How many copies?", Type:=1)
    StartNumber = Application.InputBox("Number to start from", Type:=1) 

    For CopyNumber = StartNumber To CopiesCount 
        With ActiveSheet
            .Range("C1") .Value = CopyNumber 
            .PrintPreview
        End With 
    Next CopyNumber 

End Sub
```

My question is, how to change the number in Excel each time I print (and for a range)

Comment: I tried to do it myself and failed miserably.

Comment: Can you edit your post and copy this in there with proper formatting? its not readable this way and that makes troubleshooting a pain. I do spot an issue. You have ActiveSheet .Range("C1").Value =... It contains a space.

Comment: no, not as a comment. Comments are only one line, no code. Press the edit button below your question

Comment: I've edited your post now

Comment: Can you try copy/paste the code I placed in your first post and see if it works? if not, what happens and what doesn't?