# Excel macro to print 3 pages with same number and then increment

Tags: microsoft-excel, printing, macros

I have an excel sheet to print a set of 3 pages which I use for a timesheet. I need some kind of macro which can change numbers after every three sheets printed . So, the first three sheets are 0001 and next three 0002 next three 0003, so on.

If possible, I need to be able to start for where I left off. Here is what I've tried so far:

```
Sub PrintCopies_ActiveSheet()

Dim CopiesCount As Long
Dim copynumber As Long

CopiesCount = Application.InputBox("How many copies do you want?", Type:=1)
'Now the program wants you to input how many pages you like to print.
'You can input 100 here.

For copynumber = 1 To CopiesCount
With ActiveSheet
   .Range("E1").Value = copynumber 'I assume your invoice number is in cell E1.
   For i = 1 To 3
    .PrintOut 'Print the sheet
End With
Next copynumber
End Sub
```

Couple of problems:

1. It doesn't print the sheet three times with the same number
2. I also need to the number to have leader zeros (eg, 0001, 0002 ... 000n)

Any solutions?

Comment: Found it and edited it a bit

Comment: Looks like you've just copied the code from http://superuser.com/questions/203892/changing-a-number-in-each-time-i-print ... How have you `edited it a bit`? Can you explain what you tried to get it working so we can see where it's gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You have already claimed you've just copied other code and not done it yourself. If you continue down this route, you'll get lost, I recommend actually learning the little code you need.

This function demos how you get the the number to increment every 3 times and how to add the leading zeros. I have assumed, as per your example (where you wrote `(eg, 0001, 0002 ... 000n)`), that you always want 3 zeros in front.

```
Sub doThis()

Dim page As Integer
page = 1

Dim pageToUse As String
pageToUse = "000" & page

Dim copyNumber As Integer
Dim copiesCount As Integer
copiesCount = 5

For copyNumber = 1 To copiesCount

    If copyNumber Mod 4 = 0 Then     'needs to be 4 as you start with 1
        pageToUse = "000" & page + 1
    End If

Next copyNumber

End Sub
```