# How to change starting invoice number in VBA loop

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Trying to implement this macro - [Changing a number in each time I print](https://superuser.com/q/203892/97028).

I am currently trying to use a macro for changing an invoice number when I am printing a batch.

```
***Sub PrintCopies_ActiveSheet()
Dim CopiesCount As Long
Dim copynumber As Long

CopiesCount = Application.InputBox("How many copies do you want?", Type:=1)
'Now the program wants you to input how many pages you like to print.
'You can input 100 here.

For copynumber = 1 To CopiesCount
With ActiveSheet
   .Range("E1").Value = copynumber 'I assume your invoice number is in cell E1.
   .PrintOut 'Print the sheet

End With
Next copynumber
End Sub***
```

It works as it is, but I want to print a batch of invoices starting at invoice number 400. When I try to change this part

```
For copynumber = 1 To CopiesCount
```

to

```
For copynumber = 400 To CopiesCount
```

it doesn't work. (This change was suggested in a comment on the accepted answer in the linked question.)

How can I change the code to let me specify the starting invoice number?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve? Setting copy number to anything other than 1 will make it try to start at that number... which I'm sure isn't really what you want. If you ask it for 401 copies & start at 400 it will print 1. It would make more sense to just ask for 1.

Comment: I'm looking to print a batch of invoices off at once with sequential numbers. I need them to start from 400 and work up from there because we have already used 1-399.

Comment: I think you may be headed in the wrong direction. From what I see here, this would not increment your invoice number. This macro appears to print the same page until the copy count is reached.

Answer (score 0):

Try this amended code. I added two new variables (`start` and `limit`) that make this code more easily customized for printing invoice numbers. There is now a second user prompt for the starting invoice number. `limit` is calculated from the two user inputs.

```
Sub PrintCopies_ActiveSheet()
Dim CopiesCount As Long
Dim copynumber As Long
Dim start as Variant, limit As Long

CopiesCount = Application.InputBox("How many copies do you want?", Type:=1)
'Now the program wants you to input how many pages you like to print.
'You can input 100 here.

'starting invoice number
start = Application.InputBox("Start sequence at what invoice number?", Type:=1)  

'This gives you the ability to cancel the macro by clicking Cancel.
If start = "False" Then
    Exit Sub
End If

limit = start + CopiesCount - 1   'last invoice number to print


For copynumber = start To limit
    With ActiveSheet
       .Range("E1").Value = copynumber 'I assume your invoice number is in cell E1.
       .PrintOut 'Print the sheet

    End With
Next copynumber
End Sub
```